# How to find out on flickr the farm-id and other info of a photo

Tags: flickr

Im trying to display in my website photos froma photoset I have in Flickr. In the documentation says:

> You can construct the source URL to a photo once you know its ID, server ID, farm ID and secret, as returned by many API methods.

But I only know how to get the Photo ID. How can I get the rest of the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest API is flickr.photos.search, and you can find the documents from

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

And an example output could be found there.

when you get the ouput, a photo could be accessed by

```
http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
```

Comment: is generated Flicker photo statik URL changing fix interval of time?

Comment: I'm new to Flickr API. Can anyone please explain what a 'farm-id' is? Thanks.